# synchronized block for a while loop's condition

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

I'm trying to fix a piece of code I've written that currently has race conditions. In doing so I need to put the condition of a `while` loop in a `synchronized` block, however I don't want to synchronise the whole `while` block since that would starve other threads of the resource, which they need. I can't figure a reasonable way of doing it without repetition or `break`s in places that slightly obscure the control flow. Below is the gist of the problem code:

```
while ((numRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer);
}
```

and I need to synchronise the use of `in`. The two potential solutions I could think of (but don't think they're very good) are:

```
synchronized (this) {
    numRead = in.read(buffer);
}
while (numRead != -1) {
    out.write(buffer);
    synchronized (this) {
        numRead = in.read(buffer);
    }
}
```

which has undesirable repetition, and this:

```
while (true) {
    synchronized (this) {
        numRead = in.read(buffer);
    }
    if (numRead == -1)
        break;
    else
        out.write(buffer);
}
```

which isn't great for readability. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could wrap that read call in a method call with synchronized block (or the method itself can be synchronized)

Comment: @mszymborski you're quite right, I think the lack of sleep is starting to show! Thanks.

Comment: I don't get what "synchronize the use of in" is supposed to accomplish. What if instead of this you have one thread reading from the stream and inserting into a blocking queue used by multiple consumers?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: @NathanHughes my use case isn't preventing multiple threads reading at the same time, it's preventing the input being changed mid-read. There's only one consumer - a tcp stream.

Comment: A TCP stream (SocketInputStream) does not change the data mid-read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like below.

```
public testMyMethod () {
    byte[] buffer = new int[1024];
    int numRead = -1;
    while ((numRead = readInput(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer);
    }
}

//first method
int readInput(byte[] buffer) {
    int readLen = -1;
    synchronized(in) {
        in.read(buffer);
    }
    return readLen;
}

//second method, more performant about 3 times, just the synchronization parts
private static final ReentrantLock inputLock = new ReentrantLock();

int readInput(byte[] buffer) {
    int readLen = -1;
    inputLock.lock();
    try {
        readLen = in.read(buffer);
    } finally {
        inputLock.unlock();
    }
    return readLen;
}
```

Comment: I'm very interested in the part where you say that `ReentrantLock` is 3 times faster than a `synchronized` block. That's a bold statement. Do you have any sources/references that back up that claim, or is it based on your own benchmarks?

Comment: both do not synchronize in `in` (but might do as well dpeending on what the reason for the synchronize is supposed to be)

Comment: @sstan it is certainly not correct, uncontended synchronized is as fast as it can get.

Comment: @sstan I remember watching a video on youtube, let me see if I can find it.

Comment: @sstan I can't find the exact video, but here's a link for performance comparision http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10264/#fig1. What the video covered was basically this. Using `synchronized` makes the thread flush and reload memory from the method which is synchronized, it doesn't matter even if synchronized is used as a block in the method. This gives performance issues, which is avoided by using Locks. If you check in the figure in the link, throughput for the Locks is about 3 times than the throughput for the synchronized.

Comment: That information is pretty old. I wonder how much of that info is still true in the latest versions of the JDK...

Comment: it's been 3 years since I watched that video. Since then I just made a rule of thumb for myself to use locks whenever I can. You're right, it's a bold statement without context.